# Mark two partition as bootable on flash drive

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I have a 64GB flashdrive split in to two partitions.

First partition (45GB).

```
1. Boot-able (grdlr)
2. Uses Easy2Boot
3. Has several bootable iso's on it using Easy2Boot
4. It is formated as FAT32
```

Second partition (19GB)

```
1. Boot-able (bootmgr)
2. Has a windows 7 32bit on it.
3. It is formated as ntfs
```

The problem that I am facing is that I can only have one marked as boot-able, so to change I have to put my Puppy Linux Live CD in my computer and make the other partition as boot-able and this can be a real pain. So if any on knows how I could make it give me the option to chose which partition I want to boot from. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could create 3 partitions, one to contain a bootloader like GRUB. When you boot to the USB it will trigger GRUB and if you configure it you could get it to boot one or other of the partitions? Don't know if it can be done because of how USB devices are addressed by a mainboard...

Comment: I don't see why not i could add another partition.

Comment: Like I said, no idea what the end result might be...!